# ZAP XSS attack trying to fix with input validation but not working?

Tags: html, validation, input, xss, zap

ZAP HTML Report stated XSS attack: 
Parameter: username 
Attack: alert(1);

How do I fix my HTML so that ZAP doesnt say there's an XSS attack on my username stuff? I know it has to do with input validation/whitelisting?

I was trying to follow this: https://tododev.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/detecting-and-fixing-xss-using-owasp-tools/

but it left me more confused, and I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [OWASP Java Encoder](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project) instead of ESAPI. An example of how to use the OWASP Java Encoder in your code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ page import="org.owasp.encoder.Encoder" %>
<%-- HTML context --%>
<body><b><%= Encode.forHtml(textValue) %>" /></b></body>
<%-- HTML Attribute context --%>
<input type="text" name="address"
value="<%= Encode.forHtmlAttribute(addressData) %>" />
<%-- HTML Content context --%>
<textarea name="text">
<%= Encode.forHtmlContent(textAreaContent>" />
<%-- Javascript Block context --%>
<script type="text/javascript"> var msg = "<%= Encode.
forJavaScriptBlock(message) %>"; alert(msg); </script>
<%-- Javascript Variable context --%>
<button onclick="
alert('<%= Encode.forJavaScriptAttribute(alertMsg) %>');
">click me</button>
```

Hope this helps!